# How to make a Start and end time picker one field only, using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-plugins

[image: Like this]

Like that, and how to create start and end time picker like datetime picker popup.

sorry for bad english

maybe like this

[image: popup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing that comes to mind is that you use 3 inputs - 2 for start and end time, 1 hidden for the combination. You style those two not to have border and wrap them in bordered div to appear as one field.
Then bind JS event listeners for change on those two visible inputs to update value (e.g. 09:00:00-17:00:00) in the hidden input and in your server-side script you get the value of the hidden input.